# AWS SAM - Copy files from local host while locally testing lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I need to copy files from a local host while testing lambda using AWS SAM. This will simulate a case when in a real scenario files are copied from S3. Is there any way to copy files from a local host inside lambda while local testing?

I was trying to mount the local directory as a volume in a Docker container which executes lambda, but it turns out that attaching volumes to a Docker container in AWS SAM is not supported yet ( here is GitHub request https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2589 which is still open )

Comment: Putting required files inside lambda `codeUri` directory allows AWS SAM to copy them as a part of container deployment process. Then you access then from within container's `/var/task` directory directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use install [localstack](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/s3/) and use that in your tests as a fake, local s3 endpoint. If pulling data from s3 is crucial for your lambda then your tests would improve in their comprehensiveness.

Comment: As for now we put required files inside lambda code directory, but this is temp solution. We will definitely use your's recommendation as a long-term solution. Thanks